# Creating an NSDictionary from an NSArray (Objective-c 2.0)

Tags: objective-c, hash, nsarray, nsdictionary

I have an `NSArray` containing n elements at indices `0, 1 ... n-1`. I want to populate an `NSDictionary` with the contents of my array.

Specifically the dictionary should contain key-value pairs where the key is the hash of the ith element in the array and the value is the index into the array.

For example: `array = [123, 101, 199]` then the dictionary will contain three key-value pairs:

- `([123 hash], 0)`
- `([199 hash], 2)`
- `([101 hash], 1)`

I've done this with a for loop over the array. **What's a more concise way to do this?** Perhaps something from NSKeyValueCoding?

**More info**: I'm thinking of something like this:

```
NSArray *keys = [myArray valueForKey:@"hash"];
NSArray *values = [myArray valueForKey:@"index"]; // @"index" needs to change
NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:values 
                                                       forKeys:keys];
```

Comment: A for loop is pretty concise. There are some different syntaxes you can use for slightly different-looking versions, but you'll still really be doing the same thing in about the same amount of code.

Comment: You're right the loop is only a few lines. I'd just like to learn more about NSKeyValueEncoding.

Comment: Ah, then you can ask about that explicitly in a different question. KVC (KeyValueCoding) is sort of orthogonal to what you're doing here. For the problem you're talking about in this question, the loop (or one of its cousins) is the right way to do it.

Comment: @quixoto I meant `KeyValueCoding` sorry.

Comment: A hash is not unique.  You'll end up with an unreliable result, no matter how you do it.

Comment: @HotLicks please elaborate. Is it possible to have `[object1 hash] == [object2 hash]` where object1 is not actually object2 in Objective-c 2.0?

Comment: Yes, by definition, `[object1 hash] == [object2 hash]` does not imply that object1 is identical to object2.  It's just that they can't be identical and have different hashes.  This has nothing to do with Objective-C.

Comment: @MrMusic: Yes, it's possible to have that in any environment. A hash is not a unique ID; it's a one-way function that takes some input and converts it into a uniformly distributed (usually smaller) output. The NSObject `hash` property consequently doesn't guarantee anything about uniqueness, and is even looser in what it requires than "hashes" as a general concept. Additionally, two objects (object1 and object2) will also have identical hashes if they contain identical data, even if they are different instances of a class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably use something like David's `for` loop solution myself, but just for kicks, and because I'm still trying to wrap my head completely around them, I came up with a solution using `blocks`:

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:[array count]];

[array enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^ (id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    [dict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedLong:idx] forKey:hashFor(obj)]; } ];
```

I'm assuming the existence of a function `hashFor` that generates the hash. You can replace that part with a message to `obj` or whatever you do to generate the hash.

Answer (score 1):

A for loop is pretty good, especially if you need the index. Otherwise you might use fast enumeration:

```
int i = 0;
for (object in array) {
  … [NSNumber numberWithInt: i] … // Add to dict
  i++;
}
```

This has nothing to do with KVC.